# How to boost document when match is found at the beginning of the text in lucene

Tags: java, android, lucene

I wanted to how's it possible. suppose i'm searching for `ka` then `Karthik` should have more score than of `Aakash`. how to boost those documents?.
 I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155001/lucene-give-more-weight-the-closer-term-is-to-beginning-of-title).

I'm trying to use `SpanFirstQuery` like shown below. but it's not working. i'm using lucene 4.0

```
//queryString is searchText. e.g ka
//NAME, ORGANIZATION_NAME and ORGANIZATION_POSITION are indexed field names.
Map<String, Analyzer> searchAnalyzers = new HashMap<String, Analyzer>();
searchAnalyzers.put(NAME, new KeywordAnalyzer());
searchAnalyzers.put(ORGANIZATION_NAME, new KeywordAnalyzer());
searchAnalyzers.put(ORGANIZATION_POSITION, new KeywordAnalyzer());
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper perFieldAnalyzerWrapper = new  PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(new KeywordAnalyzer(), searchAnalyzers);
MultiFieldQueryParser multiFieldQueryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_40, mSearchFields, perFieldAnalyzerWrapper); //mSearchFiels is array of fiels
multiFieldQueryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
Query query = (Utils.isEmpty(queryString)) ? new MatchAllDocsQuery() : multiFieldQueryParser.parse(QueryParser.escape(queryString)); //queryString is text to be searched

Term term = new Term(NAME, queryString);
SpanFirstQuery spanFirstQuery = new SpanFirstQuery(new SpanTermQuery(term), 5);
spanFirstQuery.setBoost(5.0f);
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.add(spanFirstQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
booleanQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
indexSearcher.search(booleanQuery, 100);
```

Comment: spanfirst is really a bad recommendation imho

Comment: do you have other requirements apart from listed in the question, e.g. if kartnik is term that every document, while Aakash is rare term, should behavior stays the same?

Comment: @Mysterion. No . no such case. behaviour should stay same like I mentioned above( in each and every case). if spanfirst is bad option, then can you suggest another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts, why *SpanFirstQuery* is a bad idea - it looks a lot like a workaround, which will likely work poorly (also, i'm not sure how to make it work at first place), in terms of performance, and also will require from you to store positions (additional space), which isn't really needed.

**Proposed solution:**

Caveat - this is experimental, probably not production ready solution, which still will require some work to do.

I used *WildcardQuery* as a basis for this functionality, since it's support queries like `*ka*`, that's what you want. Second problem - scoring, since *WildcardQuery* is a subclass of *MultiTermQuery*, you could specify custom rewrite method:

```
public class BoostPrefixScoringRewrite extends ScoringRewrite<BooleanQuery.Builder> {

    private final String text;

    public BoostPrefixScoringRewrite(String text) {
        // todo should be handled more carefully, since wildcard query supports other than * symbols
        this.text = text.replace("*", "");
    }

    @Override
    protected BooleanQuery.Builder getTopLevelBuilder() {
        BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        builder.setDisableCoord(true);
        return builder;
    }

    protected Query build(BooleanQuery.Builder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addClause(BooleanQuery.Builder topLevel, Term term, int docCount,
                             float boost, TermContext states) {
        final TermQuery tq = new TermQuery(term, states);
        if (term.text().startsWith(this.text)) {
            // experiment with the boost value
            topLevel.add(new BoostQuery(tq, 100f), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        } else {
            topLevel.add(new BoostQuery(tq, boost), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void checkMaxClauseCount(int count) {
        if (count > BooleanQuery.getMaxClauseCount())
            throw new BooleanQuery.TooManyClauses();
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the boosting value, now it's hardcoded to 100, which should be enough to always place terms starting with search text on top. Also, the thing to look at - if your term list will broad, with Boolean rewrite, you could face **TooManyClauses** exception, than you will need to have a workaround, to increase this number, or to rewrite this query differently.

For full test take a look here - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/master/lucene5/src/main/java/org/mystic/BoostBeginningWithTest.java