# Solr search from left

Tags: apache, search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

**Hi** on Solr I send this query and i get

**select?fl=productName&indent=on&q=Test&wt=json**

```
{ productName: "Máquina Test Eletrônica 7mm com Motor Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Test Pesada"},
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica Direct Drive com Caixa Acoplada"},
{ productName: "Máquina Test Eletrônica com Motor Direct Drive 110V"},
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica Cabeçote Longo 80cm Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Costura Test Eletrônica" },
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica com Refilador e Motor Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica Rolamentada Leve com Motor Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Test Transporte Triplo"}
```

**But I Want This. A Left to Right result**

```
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica com Refilador e Motor Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica Direct Drive com Caixa Acoplada"},
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica Rolamentada Leve com Motor Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Test Eletrônica Cabeçote Longo 80cm Direct Drive"},
{ productName: "Test Pesada"},   
{ productName: "Test Transporte Triplo"}
{ productName: "Costura Test Eletrônica" },
{ productName: "Máquina Test Eletrônica com Motor Direct Drive 110V"},
{ productName: "Máquina Test Eletrônica 7mm com Motor Direct Drive"},
```

**productName is text_general field type**

Comment: Did you try `q=productName:Test`

Comment: I try q=productName:Test but get the same result

Comment: You can try a regex search `productName:/^Test.*/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lucene - give more weight the closer term is to beginning of title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155001/lucene-give-more-weight-the-closer-term-is-to-beginning-of-title)