# How to do SpanFirstQuery in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, startswith

We have requirement to bring documents at top where keyword starts in a title at beginning something like below:

```
Document 1: Solr home page
Document 2: Its Solr home page
```

**When search for the keyword Solr,** **Document 1 should come at first**

By browsing the same ask, understood that we can achieve this using SpanFirstQuery as explained in below link

[lucene - give more weight the closer term is to beginning of title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155001/lucene-give-more-weight-the-closer-term-is-to-beginning-of-title)

However, above link demonstrated using Lucene. Considering Solr is superset of the Lucene query syntax, understood that we can achieve it by doing few adjustments.

Please guide how to implement the same in Solr.

Comment: Have you seen the XML Query Parser? That should support giving specific span query types: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/other-parsers.html#xml-query-parser